# Load base data in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm new to Windows 8 app development. I'm trying to port a old application I wrote in .NET. This application uses base data which is stored as four XML files that were added to the project as "Ressource" and deserializes them using the System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.

What would be the best way to ship data like this with an Windows 8 Store App? Just put them in the Assets Folder?

What is the best way to load and bind data like this in an Windows 8 app?

I'm grateful for everything you can give me, a direct answer, helpful links or an video on data loading and binding in Windows 8 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use resources in store app, here is the example :

```
public static string GetXmlContentsFromResource(Assembly asm, string dataName)
{
  string contents = "";

  Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + "." + dataName);
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  return contents;
}
```

You should add XML files to solution and mark it as "Embedded Resource", and if you put XML files in subdirectory, for example if folder is named Data and xml file is Data1.xml then you should send parameter dataName to above method like this "data.Data1.xml".

For Data Binding best aproach is to deserialize that XML to object or list of objects that reflects XML contents.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I used the XmlSerializer.Deserialize method directly with the Stream. I will check out chue x's links anyways, because I think async operations are important for my future programming.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best way to ship data like this with an Windows 8 Store App? Just put them in the Assets Folder?

Yes, put them in your assets folder. Be sure to set the build properties to "Content" + "Copy To Output".  Once you have done this, you can access them from your app using the following url: `ms-appx:///Assets/myxmlfile.xml`

For example:

```
StorageFile xmlFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync
    (new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/myxmlfile.xml"));
```

The above gives you a file object that you can use to read your file. Obviously, since you are reading from the `Assets` folder, your file will be read-only.

> What is the best way to load and bind data like this in an Windows 8 app?

As to data binding, that is probably a bit too large to cover in one answer. You might want to take a look at this [Windows 8 Data Binding Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer. I can't use await in the method I'm loading the data, so I added a `.GetResults()` to the `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` call. But it is raising an exception "a method was called at an unexpected time", I'm not sure, if this is because of my change or a general problem...

Comment: @Hinek - What is the reason you are not able to call `await`? If you are unfamiliar with how `async` and `await` works that is a very broad topic. See this link for a start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Many times people think they can't use async calls because it does not work with their existing code. The problem is most of these Async calls have continuations on the same thread so calling GetResult causes a deadlock. Async is contagious and often requires changing a lot of code, but it's also the only choice.

Comment: When I used await the Compiler threw an error, plus the app can't really do anything before this data is loaded (which shouldn't take too long, it's 1-2 seconds on my phone device ... shouldn't be longer on a tablet or PC) ... so I don't see a gain too do it async at this point. But I will check out your link, async operations are important, I know. Thanks for your help!